# Real Analysis question about polygons and derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

So.. I honestly have no idea what to do here. Any help at all is appreciated.

Comment: For part iii), it says the theorem from class... Can you tell us this theorem?

Comment: The partition should be $$\mathcal{P}\, : \, x_0 = a < x_1 < \cdots < x_{n+1} = b$$
For part (i), if we call $g$ the approximation, you could try something like $g(x_i) = f(x_i)$, for $0\leq i\leq n+1$, and $g$ is linear between $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ (here, $0 \leq i \leq n$).  Then use the distance formula for each segment, and it should give what you need for part (i).

Comment: @SujaanKunalan Give me a few, im looking in my notes now, ill write back when i find something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The points in the graph given by the partition are $(x_i,f(x_i))$. We approximate the length of the curve by the distances between these point. The distance between two consecutive points is

$$\sqrt{(x_{i+1}-x_i)^2+(f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i))^2}$$

So, we approximate the length of the graph by

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sqrt{(x_{i+1}-x_i)^2+(f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i))^2}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}(x_{i+1}-x_i)\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)}{x_{i+1}-x_i}\right)^2}$$

This is part (i).

By the intermediate value theorem $\frac{f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)}{x_{i+1}-x_i}=f'(s_i)$, with $s_i\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]$. Then we can rewrite the sum above as

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}(x_{i+1}-x_i)\sqrt{1+(f'(s_i))^2}$$

This solves (ii)

Now, this is a Riemann sum for the integral

$$\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}\text{d}x$$

Since $f'$ is continuous, the Riemann sums converge to the integral as the partition shrinks. This is part (iii).